# C++ Searching object in nested pair of an std::set

Tags: c++, stl, set, std-pair

I have an STL set of type:

`std::set< std::pair< double, std::pair< unsigned, vector< unsigned > > > > X`

I know I could make things simpler by changing my data structure but that's not an option here for me.

How can I search for an element of type `unsigned` only in the first elements of the inner pair in my set?

I tried the following approach, but doesn't work.

```
auto it = std::find_if(X.begin(), X.end(), [value_searching]
(const std::pair<double, std::pair< unsigned, vector< unsigned > >& elem) {
return elem->second.first == value_searching
        });
```

Comment: Only a pointer or iterator should be left of `->`.  `elem` is neither - it's a `pair`.

Comment: What would be the alternate approach for this case? @aschepler

Comment: Such complex structure never make sense in real live... It make the code hard to maintain as you have multiple first and second... Also, it might not be as efficient as you would like... why do you use a set if you dont use the key to find items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.` instead of `->`, because `elem` is a reference, not a pointer, to a `pair`.

```
auto it = std::find_if(X.begin(), X.end(), [value](auto& elem) {
  return elem.second.first == value;
});
```

Comment: in this way I can only do (elem.second) but (elem.second.first) doesn't work

Comment: @FabiaBushraTamanna In what way doesn't it work? Works for me.

Comment: My bad, I missed a '>' in my set declaration @joseph